# On form post, old page is shown briefly before redirecting

Tags: php, forms, redirect

I'm sending off a php mail upon submission of this form. I want the page to redirect after submission. The problem I'm having is the form submits, the old page reloads, then the redirection kicks in. Any thoughts on how I can skip the reload and just do the redirect? Code below:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['button_pressed']))
        {
        $to ='email@email.com';
        $subject = 'New Sign Up!';
        $message = $_POST['MERGE1'] . ' ' . $_POST['MERGE2'] . ' with the email address ' . $_POST['MERGE0'] . ' has just registered using the Sign Up Now Popup Form';
        $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
                                            'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
                                            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        $url = 'http://www.example.com/?sub=true';
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the below lines from:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/?sub=true';
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';
```

to:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/?sub=true';
header("Location:" . $url)
```

Comment: You should add `exit();` after the redirect header for security reason. Web client can ignore the redirect header.

Comment: This is what I was trying to do first but when I add the header command, then page still refreshes on button press and then the redirect doesn't even kick in. Any thoughts?

Comment: ACtually just realized the problem was with my form action. That was causing the refresh and after a very long day it didn't even occur to me.

Answer (score 0):

The header() function sends a raw HTTP header to a client.

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/?sub=true');
```